# CAN Bus Dominant and Recessive?

Tags: automotive, can, bus, networking, canopen

Why does CAN Bus represents signals with an inverted logic, high voltage for a logic 0 and low voltage for a logic 1?
Is there any advantage in doing so?

Comment: None, just as RS232 has inverted polarity compared to basic UART signals.

Comment: Are you done with this question now? If so then please formally accept an answer else raise a comment for further clarification. You can leave your own answer if you found a better explanation and formally accept that if you wish. It needs to be closed down.

Comment: "Why does CAN Bus represents signals with an inverted logic". It doesn't. It's a differential signal. If you look at the decoded differential "CANH minus CANL" then it is positive logic. Same thing if looking at Tx from a CAN controller towards the transceiver. You might be confusing _dominant_ bits (0) and _recessive_ bits (1) for the logical levels active high/low.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with arbitration of the bus. Each node on the network must observe the bus at all times, even when transmitting. If a node is transmitting a recessive bit and it detects a dominant bit, it must instantly stop transmitting. This is known as the collision avoidance.

**How does this relate to arbitration?**
Every CAN frame starts with a start of frame (SOF) bit and then the CAN ID is transmitted, MSB first. The lower the CAN ID, the earlier a dominant bit is going to be transmitted. Assuming multiple devices start transmitting at the exact same time, the device with the lowest ID will be the first to transmit a 0, so other devices will detect this as a collision (they will be transmitting a 1, while sensing a 0) and stop transmitting further bits.

[image: Example with 3 nodes]

Comment: I think this does not answer the asked question why dominant is 0 and recessive 1, as it could be chosen the other way around too and work equally.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because pullup resistors might create the HIGH, which will put the CAN driver into recessive mode, allowing other drivers to use the bus.

Part of fail-safe thinking.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why does CAN Bus represents signals with an inverted logic, high
> voltage for a logic 0 and low voltage for a logic 1?*

CAN bus has two data wires: -

[image]

[image]

Pictures from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#:%7E:text=The%20dominant%20state%20is%20transmitted,and%20CANL%20at%205%20V.).

Therefore it drives one high whilst driving the other low. The fact that CAN Hi happens to be a high voltage when a logical 0 is being produced is countered by CAN Lo being a zero.

Comment: While this correctly answers the question "how high speed CAN works", the correct answer to the question "why does CAN Bus represents signals with an inverted logic" would be: "it does not". It is also better because it applies to both high and low speed CAN bus, which this answer does not.

Answer (score 0):

High is the default state for the tranceiver, it allows all other nodes to overwrite the bits by pulling it low. As used in the arbitration process or error flags.

If it were reversed overwriting bits would be difficult since it would require a large amount of current going into the active transceivers.

Comment: "High is the default state for the tranceiver" is only true for CAN L line of low speed bus and only because of pull-up. The transceiver's default state is actually high impedance. The rest of the answer is nonsensical.